# How to load a class in Ruby from another folder while running tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-io

I am trying to write some tests for a Poker application I've written in Ruby. I get a `cannot load such file -- test_car (LoadError)` error when I try to run my tests however. This is what my file directory structure looks like:

```
Poker    
   lib
      Card.rb
      Player.rb
      Game.rb    
   Test
      test_card.rb
```

At the top of test_card.rb, I have `require 'Card'`, but I am not sure how to load it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in a Ruby project you create a `test_helper.rb` file that sets up the load path for you. I would recommend organizing things like this:

```
Poker
  lib
    card.rb
    player.rb
    game.rb
  test
    card_test.rb
    test_helper.rb
```

In `test_helper.rb`:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__))
```

Then in `card_test.rb`:

```
require_relative "test_helper"
require "card"
```

Also note that the convention in Ruby is to use all-lowercase for filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You should describe the path while you are running your tests through `I` flag, as shown in the following line of code:

```
ruby -I../lib/ test_card.rb
```

`..` takes you to the parent folder - in your case, that is root of your Poker application.

Comment: That worked perfectly, but I'm wondering if there is a way to put that in the code? So that it can be run from the terminal by just writing 'ruby test_card.rb'?

Comment: @PowerProject Through command line, not any that I'm aware of.